# Very nooby inquiry input and if statements

Tags: java

I'm completely new to programming and am just messing around with what I know so far. I am making a primitive "AI" of sorts that asks simple questions. In this part of the code, the program asks "Where do you live?" and "Do you like living there?" I am trying to make it so that if the user inputs anything but variations of No or Yes, the bot will ask the question again. Here is what I have so far

```
        System.out.println("I have never been to " + line3 + " before. Do you like it there?");

    // Wait for user to enter a line of text
    String line4 = input.nextLine();

    if(line4.equals("Yes")){
        System.out.println("That's good! I'm glad to hear it.");
    }
        else if(line4.equals("No")){

            System.out.println("Oh no! You should move then!");

        }
        else if(line4.equals("no")){

            System.out.println("Oh no! You should move then!");

        }
        else if(line4.equals("yes")){

            System.out.println("That's good! I'm glad to hear it.");

        }
```

How would I go about doing this? Also, is there an easier way to accomplish what I've already written in the code? I would have to make an else if statement for every different Yes/No possible, for example, I would need a different else if for "Yes!" or "Not at all!" etc. etc.

Much thanks in advance

Comment: Your code is not complete, please put complete code..... Instead of separate `no` and `No`,  you can use ignore case.

Answer (score 1):

One option, use an infinite loop (and `equalsIgnoreCase`); like

```
String line4 = input.nextLine();
while (true) {
    if (line4.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        System.out.println("That's good! I'm glad to hear it.");
        break;
    } else if (line4.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
        System.out.println("Oh no! You should move then!");
        break;
    }
    line4 = input.nextLine();
}
```

Another option, use a [`Map<String, String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and a loop like

```
Map<String, String> msgMap = new HashMap<>();
msgMap.put("yes", "That's good! I'm glad to hear it.");
msgMap.put("no", "Oh no! You should move then!");
// ...
String line4;
do {
    line4 = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    if (msgMap.containsKey(line4)) {
        System.out.println(msgMap.get(line4));
    }
} while (!msgMap.containsKey(line4));
```

And another option, extract the prompt and input to a helper method like

```
static boolean getYesOrNo(Scanner scanner, String msg) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(msg);
        String v = scanner.nextLine();
        if (v.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            return true;
        } else if (v.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you might call it like

```
if (getYesOrNo(input, "Do you like living there?")) {
    System.out.println("That's good! I'm glad to hear it.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Oh no! You should move then!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move ask function to a separate method and use it in recursion (or cobine it with Elliott Frisch answer):

```
public static boolean askUser(String question) {
    System.out.println(question);
    String answer = input.nextLine();
    if ("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
        return true;
    } else if ("no".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return askUser(question);
    }
}
```

So now you can use it in this way:

```
String prevLine = "Boston";
    String question = "I have never been to " + prevLine + " before. Do you like it there?";
    boolean answer = askUser(question);
    if (answer) {
        System.out.println("That's good! I'm glad to hear it.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Oh no! You should move then!");
    }
```

Or again wrap it in a map